# How to map JPA objects to DB as well as file system

Tags: jpa

I have a JPA object which is mapped to table in DB and to all the columns. Out of those columns, one column stores the location of a file on file system.

So Whenever I retrieve this data, is it also possible to get the file contents?

Ex: User table is mapped to User object and that User table has column by name picture which stores the url of that file. Whenever I retrieve the Users, can I also retrieve the file contents? If so how does my mapping look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You'll have to do it by yourself, or store the contents in the file in the database, as a blob, instead of storing it on the file system.

Comment: I don't want DB to hold blob...Ya the example looks simple and DB can hold small images but there are other scenarios where file size is huge. Is there a way or interceptor while retrieving the data I can fetch file contents too?

Comment: Add a `getData()` method to your entity that uses the file name, reads from the file and returns the data.